# How to use custom DAG graph (dictionary) with a list of inputs?

Tags: python, dask

I created a custom DAG dictionary according to https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/custom-graphs.html which can take 1 input file. Now, I want to feed it a list of files but without repeating the items in the DAG as shown in the above link. I'm aware of the `delayed` functionality at: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed.html, but I need to use `get` to evaluate the DAG right? If so, how can I use it with `delayed` or `futures`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dask graphs contain a key/value pair for each task.

Without knowing the precise context of your question, you could have a function build a dask graph for each input file. Its execution could then be outsourced to its own function, which you could further parallelise using the `dask.delayed` framework. Here's a code example:

```
import dask

def produce_dask_graph_for_filename(filename):

    graph = dict()

    # this task reads the data from the file
    graph['data'] = (lambda x: x, filename)

    # this task processes the data
    graph['result'] = (lambda x: x[-1], 'data')

    return graph

def compute_result(filename):

    # create the filename specific graph
    graph = produce_dask_graph_for_filename(filename)

    # perform the computation
    result = dask.get(graph, 'result')

    return result

filename_list = ['file_%s' %i for i in range(5)]

futures = [dask.delayed(compute_result)(filename) for filename in filename_list]

results = dask.compute(futures)[0]
```

Output gives:

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

You can then visualise the individual graphs using the following line (make sure to have graphviz and python-graphviz installed)

```
dask.visualize(produce_dask_graph_for_filename(filename))
```

Comment: Thanks @malbert! However, the only way I could get it working is by removing the `dask.delayed` decorator on `compute_result`. Else, `results` just returns a list of `Delayed` objects. 
Also, after this correction, `results` is a tuple and has no attribute `visualize`. How would you recommend getting this working?

Comment: Hi @aaron02, I corrected a wrong function name and take only the first entry of the tuple returned by dask.compute. The code works for me. Which version of dask and python are you running?

Comment: Hi @malbert, i'm using dask 1.2.2 and Python 3.6. For me `dask.compute(futures)[0]` is also returning a list of Delayed objects. Not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: Sorry wrong link, here it goes again https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/quakberto/misc_jupyter_notebooks/master?filepath=test_dask_graph.ipynb

Comment: thanks! And what if I wanted to `visualize` the dag?

Comment: I added to my answer how to visualize

Comment: Thanks, but that only visualizes one graph for one file right? In essence, the code is computing multiple dags, one for each file, in a multi-processes manner, so visualize should show accordingly right?

Comment: At the end, there are two graphs here: One is your custom graph analysing a given file. The second one would be the graph which dask computes internally when you compute tasks defined with the delayed decorators. In this second graph, the computation of your custom graphs is shown as one single task. I think you need to explain more precisely explain what you want to do..

Comment: You can use this line to visualise the second, dask internal graph: `dask.visualize(dask.delayed(list)(futures))`